# Imploding an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

Say I have an array:

```
$array = Array(
  'foo' => 5,
  'bar' => 12,
  'baz' => 8
);
```

And I'd like to print a line of text in my view like this:

"The values are: foo (5), bar (12), baz (8)"

What I could do is this:

```
$list = Array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $list[] = "$key ($value)";
}
echo 'The values are: '.implode(', ',$list);
```

But I feel like there should be an easier way, without having to create the `$list` array as an extra step. I've been trying `array_map` and `array_walk`, but no success.

So my question is: what's the best and shortest way of doing this?

Comment: I dunno of a built-in function for this. Only of var_export and var_dump but they both show it in a diff format than what you want

Comment: I suggest also to take a look at [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function. It doesn't format the output the way you asked but it's very easy to implement.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem with `array_map` is that the callback function does not accept the key as an argument. You could write your own function to fill the gap here:

```
function array_map_assoc( $callback , $array ){
  $r = array();
  foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    $r[$key] = $callback($key,$value);
  return $r;
}
```

Now you can do that:

```
echo implode(',',array_map_assoc(function($k,$v){return "$k ($v)";},$array));
```

Comment: Nice! I've upvoted all the answers as well, but I'm going for this one :) Easily to add in a single line and still pretty flexible.

Comment: Wouldn't it produce an extra array traversal (one for `array_map_assoc`, another one for `implode`)?

Answer (score 38):

For me the best and simplest solution is this:

```
$string = http_build_query($array, '', ',');
```

[http_build_query (php.net)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: This is the best solution for me. Simple and no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: this is kind of cool, but with the encoding, you might not get what you wanted. But works well for simple cases.

Comment: With this method you cannot change the equal operator, which was requested.

Comment: Note this function URL-encodes keys and values source array.

Comment: This should be `$string = urldecode (  http_build_query($array, '', ',')  )  ;` to get none ASCII string.

Comment: I end up with most of the array values missing in my case. build query filtered them out.

Answer (score 10):

There *is* a way, but [it's pretty verbose](http://codepad.org/kgimPh7Y) (and *possibly* less efficient):

```
<?php
$array = Array(
  'foo' => 5,
  'bar' => 12,
  'baz' => 8
);

// pre-5.3:
echo 'The values are: '. implode(', ', array_map(
   create_function('$k,$v', 'return "$k ($v)";'),
   array_keys($array),
   array_values($array)
));

echo "\n";

// 5.3:
echo 'The values are: '. implode(', ', array_map(
   function ($k, $v) { return "$k ($v)"; },
   array_keys($array),
   array_values($array)
));
?>
```

Your original code looks fine to me.

Comment: You can replace `create_function()` (which is not better than `eval()`, because it uses `eval()` ;) just a side note) in php5.3 with `function ($k, $v) { return "$k ($v)"; }`

Comment: @KingCrunch: Indeed, an actual lambda is better in 5.3. However, I still write `create_function()` (which is just fine because there is no user-provided code here.. let's leave out the totally irrelevant `eval()`-bashing) until 5.3 is widespread on production platforms.

Comment: @KingCrunch: (I edited my question to sidestep my aversion for variable interpolation, though.)

Comment: I usually give both the 5.3-closure- as well as the pre-5.3-`create_function()`-solution too. I didn't want to start the old `eval()`-discussion again, I just thought its worth to note. However, with the 5.3-closures I don't think, its "too" verbose. I like that `array_map()` (and such) stuff :)

Comment: @KingCrunch: Perhaps :) I'll edit it in. Alas, with `array_map`, you still have to provide the keys and values as separate arrays.. which is ew.

Answer (score 8):

You could print out the values as you iterate:

```
echo 'The values are: ';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $result .= "$key ($value),";
}
echo rtrim($result,',');
```

Comment: @yi_H, exactly; that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Turn the echos into a variable and after the foreach: `echo trim($variable, ',');`

Comment: outside the loop: `$comma = '';` inside at the beginning of loop `echo $comma;` inside at the end of loop `$comma = ',';`

Comment: Feels like `trim()` and `$comma = '';` leads more and more into hacks. Seems not that clean to me.

Comment: This is just a less neat version of the OP's original approach.

Answer (score 3):

Taking help from the answer of @linepogl, I edited the code to make it more simple, and it works fine.

```
function array_map_assoc($array){
  $r = array();
  foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    $r[$key] = "$key ($value)";
  return $r;
}
```

And then, just call the function using

```
echo implode(' , ', array_map_assoc($array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the solution proposed by **Roberto Santana** its the most usefull. Only one appointmen, if you want to use it for parse html attributes (for example data), you need double quotation. This is an approach:

```
Example: var_dump( '<td data-'.urldecode( http_build_query( ['value1'=>'"1"','value2'=>'2' ], '', ' data-' ) ).'></td>');

Output: string '<td data-value1="1" data-value2=2></td>' (length=39)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with

```
    foreach ($array as &$item)
    {
        $item = reset($item);
    }
    $array = implode(', ', $array);
    var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way :

- I firstly define a new array to fill with the values of my existing
  array
- I check if my associative array is set and is not empty
- Then loop on my array and fill the new one with the values
- After the loop has terminated, i implode the new array

as you can see :

```
$new_array = [];

if (isset($array) && $array != null) {
    foreach ($array as $el) {$new_array[] = $el->value;}
    $new_array = implode(',', $new_array);
}

echo $new_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

echo json_encode($array);
if it isn't a valid array it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Loop throw the array and put `,` expect the end of loop.

```
$index = 0; // index
$len = count($array); // Length of the array

// Loop throw the array
foreach($array as $key => $a) {
   echo "$key ($a)" . ($index != $len - 1 ? ',' : '');
   $index++;
}
```