# How to add values to string in foreach?

Tags: php

I have an array with lots of information. I want to extract some of the information:

*to a string
*To a new array

I tried doing this for a string:

```
$output;
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output = $output . $post->link;
}
echo $output;
```

but the $output inside the foreach is undefined.

Is this a good solution? In that case how do I declare a variable with the right scope?

Comment: can you show us a sample of the data your trying to loop through please?

Comment: `$output = '';` before `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the variable before using it in `foreach`. Like:

```
$output="";
```

instead of

```
$output;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your error appears because you're not initialising the `$output` variable at the beginning.

Try `$output = "";` instead.

But on the other hand, a more elegant solution would be to use PHP's built-in `implode()` method.

Manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

You could do something like this:

```
$output = implode(" ", $response->data);

echo $output;
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to 'implode' associative arrays, *linepogl*'s answer to this question provides a nice example: [Imploding an associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556985/imploding-an-associative-array-in-php)

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here's an updated code that actually deals with the `->link` part of your question:

```
$response_array = array();

foreach ($response->data as $post) {
    $response_array[] = $post->link;
}

$output = implode(" ", $response_array);

echo $output;
```

Comment: what if its associative array...?

Comment: Hm, given that the OP is accessing the property `$link` of each element of `$response->data` you should maybe rather implode the results of `array_map()` using an anonymous function, which returns the `$link` property ;-)

Comment: Yes, Havelock. Great point. I've update my answer to treat that case. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: $response_array = [] gives error for me --> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Sorry, ViPiN -- bad RoR habits. Corrected the example. Use `= array()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$output = '';
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output = $output . $post->link;
}
echo $output;
```

.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = '';
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output .= $post->link;
}
echo $output;
```

or you can use `join`

```
$output = join('',$response->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$output = '';
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output .= $post->link;
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: How's that different from what the OP's currently doing?

Comment: @AmalMurali well that was typo... ohhhh you are quick to judge... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$output = '';
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output .= $post->link;
}
echo $output;
```

First you need to initialize the $output value as null thenonly in foreach loop concat the result to the $output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output[] = $post->link;
}


foreach( $output as $key => $value ){
    echo $value;
}
```

To your code you might do:

```
$output = NULL;
foreach ($response->data as $post){
    $output .= $post->link;
}

echo $output;
```