# Simple Array to String Conversion

Tags: php

I have an array from a SQL query which looks like this:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "a" [0]=> string(1) "a" } 
[1]=> array(2) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "b" [0]=> string(1) "b" } }
```

I want to turn it into a list, so it looks like this:

'a','b'

I've tried various methods from around the site/google, but can't seem to get anything working.
They include:

```
implode(',',$arr);
```

---

```
$list='';
foreach($arr as $row){
$list=$list+$row['ID'];
}
```

Comment: What all methods have you already tried but failed?

Comment: Start by modifying your SQL query call so that it returns either an associative or an enumarated array, but not both

Comment: yes, noted, I've altered the fetch statement to $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  makes the array much easier to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, turn your array into an array, containing only the IDs with quotemarks around them (array_map), then join them together with a comma (join):

```
echo join(', ', array_map(
  function($item) { return "'" . $item['ID'] . "'"; },
  $your_array));
```

Comment: Note that join is now an alias of implode so you should use implode directly.

Comment: @Technoh: yes, they both perform the same operation, so I don't see any advantage of using one over the other.

Comment: Have accepted this because, a. it was first and b. the explanation meant I understood how the answer worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$test = "'".implode("','",$arr)."'";
```

for assoc array try

```
$test = "'".implode("','",array_map_assoc(function($k,$v){return "$v";},$arr))."'";
```

Comment: I tried that before, doesn't work...  Array to string conversion

Comment: check for assoc array. Also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556985/imploding-an-associative-array-in-php